# jQuery collects 2 points of data, even though only one is assigned

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Quick question on the `.data()` in jQuery: My variable "valone" reaches into a dropdown menu within some HTML for the "data-whatever" value in the dropdown and then plugs it into the jQuery equation. But it also seems to be getting the "option value" value from the dropdown and includes it into the math somehow, even though I don't specify it to do so...

```
var valone = $('#os0 option:selected').data('whatever');
```

Am I missing something in this `.data()` function? Or do I have something extra that is not necessary?
(I have the complete jQuery and HTML below.)

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var valone = $('#os0 option:selected').data('whatever');
var valtwo = $('#os1').val();
var valthree = $('#os2').val();
var total = ((valone * 1) * (valtwo * 1) * (valthree * 1));
$('.calc').each(function(){
if($(this).val() != '')
{
total += parseInt($(this).val());
}
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select style="width: 190px;" class="calc"
name="os0" id="os0" type="text">
<option value="250" data-whatever="5">250
</option>
<option value="500" data-whatever="6">500 </option>
<option value="1000" data-whatever="7">1000
</option>
<option value="2000" data-whatever="8">2000
</option>
<option value="5000" data-whatever="9">5000
</option>
</select>
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's working as expected for me. Here's a fiddle showing that data('whatever') is only returning the value of the data-whatever attribute. http://jsfiddle.net/craigm/MdXzD/

Comment: @Aaron: What is your expected output for `250`, `250`, `250`?

Comment: Well I'm looking for the "data-whatever" value to be the value for valone, as valtwo ends up being "3" and valthree is "2". So the total should be calculated to: 5*3*2=30. But it ends up doing 250 somewhere and I end up with a total of 269 something...

Comment: @Aaron: The `$(".calc").each(...)` line is going to add the `250` back in. Could that be your issue?

Comment: That's brilliant, I didn't even think about it, that's probably my issue. I have the script auto-calculate the total everytime an option is changed though... is the `$(".calc).each` line the one that lets this happen? What should I change it to in order to avoid "250" coming back into the equation, but still auto-calculate?

Comment: @Aaron: the line in question is simply iterating over elements with class `calc` (it is not an event handler). You could separate the two pieces of code to calculate total into two separate event listeners (if I understand the problem correctly)

Comment: @Andrew: I actually just deleted the whole line which resolved my problem. I cannot begin to tell you how thankful I am for your constant help, sir. Many thanks, you've solved my issue.

Comment: @Aaron: No problem, glad you figured it out. Should I add my comment as an answer?

Comment: @Aaron: Absolutely, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.data` is retrieving the correct value. The problem occurs with this piece:

```
$('.calc').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() != '')
    {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    }
});
```

The variable `total` is computed above this point is what you expect. `.each` is iterating over each `select` element again and adding the selected value to the total.

Answer (score -1):

In answer to your question, you are missing nothing. Data stores one thing, the value set to it, either the hardcoded value in the element attribute, or the one set via jquery. What is the point in doing valone * 1, why not just valone? you are over complicating it. It should be

```
var total = valone * valtwo * valthree;
```

or

```
var total = (valone * valtwo) * valthree`; //valone will be multiplied with valtwo first before multiplying that total with valthree
```

Depending on what you are calculating.

Comment: `* 1` is implicitly converting those values to integers.

Comment: Exactly, but I'm still confused as to why I run the code, it ends up including "option value" and "data-whatever" in the same equation, even though I don't call for "option-value"...